# SQLAlchemy how to use a "fully module-qualified path"?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm contributing to a project that is using sqlalchemy. This project has a model.py file where they define all their classes, for example `Foobar(BASE)`. Now, I've created *another* module mymodel.py where I need to extend some of those classes. So for example, in mymodule.py I have `Foobar(model.Foobar)`   which I use to extend the parent class with new properties and functions. The problem is that when using either of those classes, I get this error from sqlalchemy: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "Foobar" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.`.
My question then is, how can I fix this error without renaming my classes? Since they are defined in a different module, how do I use a "fully module-qualified path"?

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue, and also struggled to understand what the error is referring to by "fully module-qualified path" or where should I make the change.

After some trial and error, the key insight for me was that **it has to do with SQLAlchemy relationships.** Furthermore, in my case it also had to do with having the same table name in different schemas (I was using Postgres).

Simplified scenario that triggered the error:

```py
# database/models/family_1.py

from database import MyOneAndOnlyBase
...

class Parent(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_1"}


class Child(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_1"}
```

```py
# database/models/family_2.py

from database import MyOneAndOnlyBase
...

class Parent(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_2"}


class Child(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_2"}
```

And the way to fix it using a fully module-qualified path:

```py
# database/models/family_1.py

from database import MyOneAndOnlyBase
...

class Parent(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("database.models.family_1.Child")
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_1"}



class Child(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_1"}
```

```py
# database/models/family_2.py

from database import MyOneAndOnlyBase
...

class Parent(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("database.models.family_2.Child")
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_2"}



class Child(MyOneAndOnlyBase):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "family_2"}
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated by SQLAlchemy there a two classes found named `Foobar`. One is `model.Foobar` and the second one is `mymodel.Foobar`. You need to use the fully module-qualified path which is `mymodel.Foobar` to reference the new class.